# Why do people work on socket.io and other Github repos for free?

Tags: github, socket.io

I have been using socket.io for a while now and was wondering how they make money from giving software for free. They seem like a successful organisation. On their Github they have over 40 contributors, I wonder how they are doing this if everything is free?

It does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the open source / freeware community. We love to build things together that goes way farther than what we could reach within our own enterprise. This is really free time we decide to give away to help built awesome project.

After, there's some company who're open sourcing some of their core modules - so they dedicate resources to maintain them. There's some people doing open source in order to get recognition or win credibility in order to take consulting contract on their open source product, etc.

There's some way people make money out of it. But mostly, it is free time gived by people who love programming.

Isaacs (actual Node.js project lead) wrote a really interesting article on the subjet recently: https://medium.com/open-source-life/d44a1953749c